# Slashes in git p4 name fails

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I am in progress of converting my Perforce repository into a git repo by using **git p4**. I have many branch mappings, some of them are circular (which is fine in Perforce) and some changed over time so they don't work from `@1`, so I start from `@50000`, otherwise **git p4** complains in several steps since the branch mappings don't reflect older integrates (anymore).

I created a dedicated branch mapping which perfectly maps two branches from `@50000`, and only these two are part of my client-specs view.

```
$ p4 workspace
View:
    //depot/feature/... //my-workspace/feature/...
    //depot/main/... //my-workspace/main/...

$ p4 branch main
View:
    //depot/feature/... //depot/main/...
```

Letting **git p4** run for a few hours returns with this:

```
$ git p4 clone --detect-branches --use-client-spec --verbose //depot@50000,1000000 .
Importing from //depot@50000,1000000 into .
[...]
Updated branches: feature main
Reading pipe: ['git', 'config', '--bool', 'git-p4.importLabels']
Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master <branch>"
executing git config --bool git-p4.useclientspec true
```

I tried a variety of different parameters, but the directory stays empty. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Which directory is it that stays empty? The work-tree? Note the second-to-last line, `Not checking out any branch`: your `git p4 clone` does not know which branch it should check-out-to-create, so it did not do it at all. I have not actually used `git p4` but I imagine `git checkout -b master p4/master` should do what you want. (Note: I've never used `git p4`.)

Comment: You actually just solved my problem! :-) Thanks Feel free to turn it into an answer that it was actually not an error, I just needed to aditionally check out the branch

Comment: I usually use `git log --graph --oneline --all` to see which branches are available and if they were converted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to run `git checkout`:

> ```
> Not checking out any branch, use "git checkout -q -b master <branch>"
> ```

In this case, `git p4 clone` didn't know which branch(es) you wanted created in your local clone, so it didn't create any, and with no branch names, did not run `git checkout` either.  It still made all the *commits*, and presumably made names `p4/master` and `p4/feature` to identify the tip commits of these two branches.